# Initialise type from address

Tags: ada, memory-address

I want to initialise a type from a `System.address`. For example :

```
generic
    type T_Generic is private;
package MyPackage is
    G_Addr : System.Address;
    procedure Register (myAddr : System.address);
    procedure MyProcedure (myAddr : System.address);
end MyPackage;

package body MyPackage is
    procedure Register(myAddr : System.address)
    is
        G_Addr := myAddr;
    end MyProcedure;

    procedure MyProcedure (myAddr : System.address)
        myVar : T_Generic with address => myAddr;
    is
        if (myAddr = G_Addr)
        then
            -- work with myVar 
        end if;
    end MyProcedure;
end MyPackage;
```

But I cannot compile this piece of code `myVar : T_Generic with address => myAddr;` :

> aspect specification is an Ada 2012 feature
>
> unit must be compiled with -gnat2012 switch

I cannot change compilation's options, how can I do ?

Comment: Maybe try `myVar : T_Generic; for myVar'Address use myAddr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I cannot compile this piece of code `myVar : T_Generic with address => myAddr;`:
>
> > aspect specification is an Ada 2012 feature
> >
> > unit must be compiled with -gnat2012 switch

```
My_Address  :  Constant System.Address:= To_Address( 16#DEAD_BEEF# );
My_Variable :  Whatever;
For My_Variable'Address use My_Address;
```

Comment: Of course, assigning an address to variable of some type does not ensure the variable contains a valid value. For instance, the size of the variable's type may not line up with data objects in surrounding memory. I wonder what A.Pissicat is trying to achieve. It would be safer to use access types instead of simply assigning a memory location to a random type.